# Tidal Force calculation on Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program that graphs the orbit of the Jupiter moon system and part of the code is suppose to calculate the tidal forces over the orbit. My goal is to be able to plot the different tidal force values as a function of distance. But, I can't seem to get it to work, i.e. it's not even printing out the tidal force values. Here's my code so far:

```
#This function requires user to input mass, semi-major axis, and the eccentricity of the satellite
def JovianSystem(m, A, e, Vi): 
    tmin = 0
    tmax = 0.0005
    dt = 0.00000001 
    M_jup = 1.898e27
    mass_ratio = m/M_jup #Mass ratio of satellite and Jupiter 
    pi = 3.14 
    G = 4*pi**2 
    alpha = 0.001
    d = []

    #Initialize Arrays for time, x and y positions, x and y velocities, and theta 
    t = np.arange(tmin, tmax, dt)
    x = np.zeros(len(t))
    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    Vx = np.zeros(len(t))
    Vy = np.zeros(len(t))
    theta = np.zeros(len(t))
    r = np.zeros(len(t))
    thetap = [0,]

    # Specify initial conditions
    x[0] = A*(1+e)                                                # initialize position of satellite in AU
    y[0] = 0
    Vx[0] = 0                                                    # initialize velocity of satellite in AU/yr
    Vy[0] = Vi* np.pi * np.sqrt((1+e)/(A*(1-e))*(1+mass_ratio))
    theta[0] = 0                                                 # initialize starting angle of satellite in Radians

    # Calculating trajectory
    for i in range(1, len(t), 1):
        theta[i] = np.arctan2(y[i-1],x[i-1])
        r = A*(1-e**2)/(1+e*np.cos(theta[i]))

        Vx[i] = Vx[i-1] - ((G*x[i-1])/(r**3)+((G*x[i-1]*alpha)/r**5))*dt
        Vy[i] = Vy[i-1] - ((G*y[i-1])/(r**3)+((G*y[i-1]*alpha)/r**5))*dt

        x[i] = x[i-1] + Vx[i]*dt
        y[i] = y[i-1] + Vy[i]*dt

        #thetap.append(theta)
        d.append(r)

    for i in range(1, len(t), 1): 
        F_tidal[i] = (2*G*M_jup*m*d)/x[i]
    print(F_tidal)
    return [x,y, F_tidal]

#x, y, thetap = JovianSystem(m,    A,     e,    Vi): 
x, y, F_tidal = JovianSystem(893.2e20, 0.0028, 0.0041, 22) 

a = 0.0028
e = 0.0041
r= sqrt(x**2+y**2)

aphelion = np.max(r)
perihelion = np.min(r)

daphelion = a*(1+e)
dperihelion = a*(1-e)

print('calculated aphelion=', aphelion)
print('calculated perihelion=', perihelion)
print('accepted aphelion=', daphelion)
print('accepted perihelion=', dperihelion)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Orbit of Io' )
plt.plot(0,0, marker='o', color = 'orange', markersize = 20)
plt.plot(0.0028,0, marker='o', color='y', markersize=10)
plt.xlabel('X (AU)')
plt.ylabel('Y (AU)')
plt.show()
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-14530b6d92c9> in <module>
      1 #x, y, thetap = JovianSystem(m,    A,     e,    Vi):
----> 2 x, y, F_tidal = JovianSystem(893.2e20, 0.0028, 0.0041, 22)
      3 
      4 a = 0.0028
      5 e = 0.0041

<ipython-input-37-b88c29847a34> in JovianSystem(m, A, e, Vi)
     43 
     44    for i in range(1, len(t), 1):
---> 45        F_tidal[i] = (2*G*M_jup*m*d)/x[i]
     46    print(F_tidal)
     47    return [x,y, F_tidal]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Any help will be much appreciated! I just want to understand what I can do to solve this problem and get Tidal force values.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that on line 45, `d` is a list, but you're trying to multiply it by a float, which could be the problem.

Comment: So I think I meant to put "r" there as opposed to "d." That fixes that problem. I think the code just doesn't like the fact that I'm multiplying the values with the "m" value which is an inputted value. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in line 45 where it looks like you have some list `d` that has some length determined by `t` and you are trying to multiple a bunch of float values against the list `(2*G*M_jup*m*d)`. This is probably not what you want to do.

For example:

```
> d = [1 ,2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
> d * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Start by answering if `F_tidal[i]` should be a list, single float value or what and the same for `d` and `x`. Depending on this, you might want to be doing matrix operations on `d` or `x`, in which case I'd point you to using [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), and in particular a numpy array rather than a list for your `d` variable.

On the other hand, if you want to be pulling individual data points from `d`, you just need to indicate it with an indexing call, i.e. `d[i]` to iterate over its values (in which case your issue is just a type or missing syntax). I.e. your line 45 should be:

```
F_tidal[i] = (2*G*M_jup*m*d[i])/x[i]
```